# Newly installed kernel runs only with initramfs> prompt

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I just compiled Linux Kernel 2.6.27.62 and installed it in Ubuntu in VitualBox.  Now, when I select the new kernel from the grub (legacy) menu, what comes out is the following:

```
[ 13.084002] cpufreq: No nForce2 chipset.
mount: mounting non on /dev/failed: No such device.
W: devtmpfs not available, falling back to tmpfs for /dev.
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/7251a301-d971-4d8e-8077-c0ca9d759aa8 on /root
failed: No such device.
mount: mount /dev/ on /root/dev/ failed: No such file or directory.
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory.
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such or directory      
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
BusyBox v7.17.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.17.1-10ubuntu1) built-in shell(ash).
```

And then I only get the `initramfs>` prompt which only provides very few commands.  Help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible workaround: 
1.Try going into grub editor during boot(press 'e' on kernel you want to boot in the grub menu). You will have a line:
"/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-23-generic root=UUID=4614036b0-1c9a-4311-b452-c5c0d3762690 ro quiet splash"

2.Remove the "root=UUID=4614036b0-1c9a-4311-b452-c5c0d3762690" and try "/dev/sda1"

Look at this post: [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1018403&page=5) (the last one on the page has screenshots)